# Is there an improvement to this DB schema and prefix like query?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've been noodling over this postgres DB schema and query for a while now and I think I need a fresh set of eyes to understand if/how it can be improved. My schema and query are rather simple which is why a query time of 600-700 MS *feels* wrong but maybe that's just what it is.

For background I have a table of IPs that contain basic information about an IP address, and a second table containing DNS names mapped back to the IP table via a has many foreign key. An example subset of the data the query in question was run against contained ~5 million IPs with ~39 million associated domains. The table schema is shown below:

[image: Table Schema]

This allows queries like the one this question is about:

```
SELECT ips.id, domain, ip FROM "ips" JOIN domains d ON ips.id = d.ip_id WHERE d.domain like '%.ford.com' ORDER BY ips.id desc LIMIT 100
```

which asks the question "give me every IP which has a DNS name ending in ford.com". The order by and limit is to enable keyset pagination described here [keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset).

An example analysis of the query is below. It averages in the 600-700ms range as I explained in the intro with most of that (94%) being the domain fuzzy search over the gin_trgrm_ops index on the domain field.

**Analysis of query**
[image: analysis of query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a classic case of rubber duck debugging! While writing this I had a great insight that greatly reduced the query times!

Suffix fuzzy searches are much faster than prefix searches. (`foo%` vs `%bar`) so what I did was use the reverse function on the domain field in the DB which results in this (`ford.com` => `moc.drof`) and switched the query to using a suffix fuzzy search:

```
SELECT ips.id, domain, ip FROM "ips" JOIN domains d ON ips.id = d.ip_id WHERE reverse(d.domain) like 'moc.drof.%' ORDER BY ips.id desc LIMIT 100
```

This results in sub 150ms queries! A good explanation of it is here: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/postgresql-fuzzy-search-best-practices-single-word-double-word-and-multi-word-fuzzy-search-methods_595635

I'm still open to suggestions on how to improve it but I'm pretty pleased with it!